# If statement in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I want to create a script that does the following:
for every directory in a path; checks if the directory's name is "profiles" and if its not that, it runs a program.

This is what i have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%i in ("\\server\c$\path\*") do (
  set filename=%%~NXi
  IF !filename!=="profiles"(
  ) ELSE (
    mycommand.exe
  )
)
```

This code just returns an "invalid command syntax" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need space before opening brackets and you need to set a command in if conditions (in this case I've set REM):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%i in ("\\server\c$\path\*") do (
  set filename=%%~NXi
  IF "!filename!"=="profiles" (
    rem :: see the space before the bracket above
  ) ELSE (
    mycommand.exe
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks :) and for future reference i also had to use quotation marks on !filename! in the IF statement. Otherwise that codeblock wouldnt trigger.

Comment: As you are working with directories, `%%NXi` will work but makes no sense, because directories don't have extensions. So `%%Ni` will be enough.

Comment: @JackPettersson - aah yes :-)

Comment: @MichaelS - not quite true :-) . `%~n` and `%~x` just split strings.If folder name contains dot it will it wont display the content after the last dot.

Comment: Folders may have an extension, why not?

Answer (score 1):

I think what your original intentions are is that you want to run a command only if the foldername is NOT "profiles". That's where the empty IF clause comes in and your use of ELSE. Compare to this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%i in ("\\server\c$\path\*") do (
  set filename=%%~nxi
  IF /I NOT "!filename!"=="profiles" (
      mycommand.exe
  )
)
```

While we're at it I've added the '/I' option to make the comparison case-independent.